# Prevent failed / interrupted cronjob from retrying

Tags: centos7, cron

I have a cronjob (on a CentOS server) which looks like this:

```
20 3 * * * wget -qO- "http://example.com/mycronfile.php?parama=1&paramb=2&paramc=3" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The PHP script is hosted locally (on the same server running the cronjob), and I have no influence on its contents or on what it's supposed to be doing.

I've noticed that the script can be a resource hog at times, and that it can occasionally take a long time to complete (30-45 minutes). Sometimes it gets interrupted (execution time runs out, or the available resources are exhausted), sometimes it finishes quickly (4-5 minutes).

The problem arises when the time / resources run out - cronjob gets restarted in that case. How can I set it up so that it can retry once, and only once, if it fails to complete the first time? Is it possible to change the parameters with which the cronjob is run, so that I can limit the job from within itself?

I realize that this is not the best way of going about it, since whatever the script is doing can be messed up, but until the owner of the script fixes it, I have to have some way of limiting it.

Comment: It's possibly duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194927/how-to-limit-shell-script-execution-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the [wGet documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Option-Syntax) (RTFM and all that), I added a `--tries=2`, which resolved my problem. With that, my cron looks like this:

```
20 3 * * * wget -qO- --tries=2 "http://example.com/mycronfile.php?parama=1&paramb=2&paramc=3" > /dev/null 2>&1
```